# Search button behaviour

Tags: search, buttons

Till recently when I pressed search button search menu appeared. But now when I click it IE opens with bing. How to change to old behaviour?

**EDIT:**
I've noticed if I go to settings > search I have disabled checkbox for "Get suggestions from Bing as I type"

Comment: I have the same problem. It just started doing this a few days ago. I didn't update the phone, it has been on mango for the last year and a half.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you experience is probably that you have changed the browser and search language

```
Settingsv -> region+language -> Browser & search language
```

Set it to English(United Kingdom) for example and then you won't see bing be opened in IE but "as an app"

Comment: That was exactly the case! I was checking how many features is my phone supporting in my native language. Damn. Thanks! Will bounty in 12 hours!

Answer (score 3):

Before the Mango update, each application could have the search button do whatever it wanted. Mango changed that, and now it will always take you to Bing search. There is nothing you can do to change it back.

**edit for comment**

What I think you saw was Bing Vision. When you press the search button you *should* be getting a screen that looks similar to the image below. Notice the red circle. That button will take you to Bing Vision search which will allow you to scan barcodes, QR codes, movies, etc....

Perhaps you had been bumping this button by mistake. As far as I know. No carrier/phone combination overrides the default search button. Every time you press it you will be taken to the Bing search page.

[image]

Comment: Its not that what I meant, few weeks ago (on mango) when in main menu I clicked search button or from lock screen. Strange search menu appeared where I could scan QR code or anything else, but now I'm directly redirected to bing.com

Comment: I want the screen you posted in image above but always when I click search button IE opens with this link:  http://www.bing.com/hp?mobref=0&setmkt=sl-SI

Comment: Slight delay in asking... but what are the 4 icons at the bottom? I only have 3: *scout*, *music*, and *vision*

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you gave in your comment to Joe, it seems like you're getting the non-mobile version of the Bing search.

Try this: after you press the search button and get to that Bing page, click on the "MOBILE" link at the top right. Does that get you to the mobile search page okay?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I checked my friends phone and it's working great there. Check my Edit above